# Is there a Python equivalent to R's invisible() function

Tags: python, r, ipython

I'm new to Python and wondering if Python (or IPython) has an equivalent to the invisible() function in R.  The invisible() function returns values, but doesn't display them if run interactively, instead it just makes them available for assignment.  For example:

```
doStuff <- function(x) {
   // blah blah 
   return(invisible(retValue))
}

z = doStuff(x) // z has the return value
doStuff(x) // retValue doesn't get displayed
```

Comment: No there is no such equivalent in Python.

Comment: Out of interest, what is the use case for something like this?

Comment: You can put a semicolon at the end of the line in IPython to suppress output e.g. `doStuff(x);`

Comment: Thanks for the info - the use is to make using things interactively much easier.  For example, I have a plot function that calculates some stats, etc and plots it.  Sometimes I would like the stats that it calculates, but don't want them needlessly displayed if I don't assign the result.  I can do the same by just making a 'returnStats' flag but don't really like that solution.

Comment: @Holloway The use case is that you can capture a value without it printing to console, retaining the information without annoying the user. Normally in Python you would use a class for this, which can be excessive.

Comment: You can e.g. return self from a method to do method chaining but in case method chaining is not used nothing will clutter the console.

Answer (score 2):

There does not seem to be a proper function in Python that is the same as R's invisible() function. However, you can simply use a variable set to a boolean value and then use an if statement to check if the boolean is set to True then you return the output of the function. Below is a simple version of what the code could look like, you can make this more complex and improve it (if this does not help you then I suggest that you put some research into function outputs in python):

```html
def function(INPUTS):
  # function code to get ouput
  return_value = False
  if return_value == True:
    return ouput
```

Comment: Depending on the use case, this could be improved using [a ternary operator](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html). For instance, `return output if return_value else " "` or alternately, `return (" ", output)[return_value]`